# Deploying a Cordova app to iOS Devices results in error cod 65

Tags: xcode, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

**UPDATE 2: FULL OUTPUT ERROR**

```
1>  (1 failure)
1>  Failed to build app for buildNumber 4548: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/4548/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,BlankCordovaApp2.xcodeproj,-target,BlankCordovaApp2,-configuration,Debug,-destination,platform=iOS,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/4548/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/4548/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/4548/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,BlankCordovaApp2.xcodeproj,-target,BlankCordovaApp2,-configuration,Debug,-destination,platform=iOS,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/4548/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/4548/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch - 1
1>  Error Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/4548/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,BlankCordovaApp2.xcodeproj,-target,BlankCordovaApp2,-configuration,Debug,-destination,platform=iOS,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/4548/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/4548/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch - {1}
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== 
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the exact error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error: Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/2108/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,Masjid Events.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,Masjid Events,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/2108/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/test/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/2108/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch - 1    BlankCordovaApp1        1
```

I have verified that there is communication between visual studio and remote build agent because deploying to iOS simulator works fine.

I have also verified that deploying to both devices works fine by deploying a sample xamarin app which works fine.

Under Platforms i am targeting Cordova CLI 6.1.1.
On the mac I have nodejs installed as well as xcode 8.1

I have also tried putting the following in my build.json and still does not work

```
{
"android": {
"release": {
  "keystore": "",
  "storePassword": "",
  "alias": "",
  "password": "",
  "keystoreType": ""
}
},
"ios": {
"debug": {
  "developmentTeam": "..."
},

"release": {
  "developmentTeam": "...",
  "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
  "packageType": "ad-hoc"
}
}

}
```

The iphone I am deploying to has (iphone5s) iOS 10.0.2 and ipad(ipad 3) is 9.3.5, let me know if any other information is required to help diagnose my issue.

In Cordova project in VS, i have tried deploying to "remote device" and "local device" while both devices were connected to the mac.

**UPDATE**:
Modified config.xml (in an text editor and added)

```
<platform name="ios">
   <hook type="before_compile" src="hooks/xcode8.js" />
</platform>
```

It states to add this before the build item, this file doesnt have a build item so i put it almost to the top so now the content looks like this

```
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.myapp23c92d" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="en-US">
   <name>BlankCordovaApp2</name>
   <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
   <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
   <content src="index.html" />
   <access origin="*" />
   <vs:features />
   <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
   <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="ios">
        <hook type="before_compile" src="hooks/xcode8.js" />
  </platform>
  ........
```

I also added the hook folder and file to both my root and www (wasnt sure which one was it suppose to go to) still doesnt work

see image
[image]

Comment: Did you Setup a `before_compile` hook in your project to copy the developmentTeam property into the project's platforms/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig file? Please check if you have followed the steps by [XCode8 build issue fix](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#xcode8)

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I made those changes as well, wasnt sure where in config.xml the build item was suppose to go.  See my update section to the original post for things i changed. thank you

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT if it snot too much trouble can you send me a sample solution that suppose to work and i will give it a shot? please and thank you

Comment: The error you posted above is a generic "Xcode failed to compile the project" error. If you go to the "output" window you will see the actual build output, and if you look near the bottom you should see a line with the particular error. If it is complaining about a missing DEVELOPMENT_TEAM then it could be that you have an error in the hook you added. If not, it will suggest where else you should look for a fix.

Comment: @Laguana added the full details of the error to the post

Comment: That is still not the full details of the error: The output log is quite a lot bigger than that, and the specific cause of the error will be listed in there somewhere towards the end. The part that you have included is just a summary stating "Something has gone wrong", so without the specific cause (likely an issue with certificates or a compilation error) we can't know how to fix the issue.